# How can I implement a cursor object that is controlled by either a keyboard or a gaming controller?

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I'm looking to implement a cursor object similar to the ones from certain tactics RPGs (think Fire Emblem, FFT, etc.), but I'd like for it to be controlled by either keyboard keys or controller buttons/joysticks so that the controls aren't "point-and-click". There's no shortage of tutorials on how to do this same thing using a mouse, but this is not the desired method for my purposes, and I'm struggling to figure out how to do the same thing, but using keys/buttons instead of a mouse. In a way, the cursor in these games *is* the player object or game manager (despite all of the fun characters and enemies), and so it's important to me that the controls and the way that they feel aren't cheapened by the relative ease and simplicity of using a mouse/mouse functions to handle the logic.

From observing the cursors across a few of the Fire Emblem titles (both 2D and 3D), I've determined that the cursor should be able to do quite a bit, including but not limited to:

- Selection and De-Selection (for which I assume the cursor probably needs to read in information from a class/struct/data structure of some sort; probably also each their own function)
- Movement **while carrying a selection** (either step-wise/tile-by-tile, or in a fluid motion)
- Remembering the previous location/data for the selection, in the event of de-selection
- Read and relay data to UI elements

To be clear, I'm **not** asking about any of the following (because so far, this is what people and Google seem to think I'm asking about):

- How to move an object (this would be fairly standard using either a key press or mouse button press function paired with a key code)
- How to perform/implement pathfinding (again, plenty of tutorials here)
- How to implement a custom mouse cursor, a la point-and-click games (this is possibly the furthest thing from what I'm trying to do at this time, as I'm just trying to get a basic, working cursor without concern for how it looks during different events)

Any help here is greatly appreciated. I realize that this is maybe not the most concise question, and that it may not be very direct, so please let me know if I can provide additional or more specific information, examples, etc.

Comment: A [search for "unity cursor gamepad"](https://search.brave.com/search?q=unity+cursor+gamepad) brings up a number of leads including a [previous question here on GDSE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/172842/33287) and docs for Unity's [VirtualMouseInput](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.UI.VirtualMouseInput.html).

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be the kind of thing that I’m looking for unfortunately, or maybe it is and I’m misunderstanding something critical here. Those results seem to be more for menu navigation tasks, as opposed to tasks involving moving characters on a playing field/map, etc. Are the concepts more similar than I’m thinking?

Comment: It sounded like you you already had the information for accomplishing the desired tasks with a mouse. Virtualizing the input is a means to abstract those solutions/ideas so that you can accomplish them with a gamepad.

Comment: Your input method should not matter regarding your four points. All of those should not the part of your input option, your input manager might keep what is selected or not and what is the previous position, but it should not care if the input data comes from the mouse, keyboard or gamepad.